# How to aggregate common values in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have following document :

```
{ asset : {
    assetName : abc,
    attributes : {
      Artist : XYZ,
      Duration : 10
     }
  }
}
{ asset : {
    assetName : pqr,
    attributes : {
      Artist : EFG,
      Duration : 5
     }
  }
}
{ asset : {
    assetName : HIJ,
    attributes : {
      Artist : XYZ,
      Duration : 10
     }
  }
}
```

I want to collect retrieve data result as follows :

```
{ result : {
   Artist: {
       values : [XYZ, EFG],
       freq : [2, 1]
   }
   Duration : {
       values : [10, 5],
       freq : [2, 1]
  }
}
```

Result should be sorted based upon the frequency.

Will be querying using mongoose package of node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/)

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate(
    [
        { "$group": { 
                      "_id":null,
                      "Artist": { "$push":"$asset.attributes.Artist" },
                      "Duration": { "$push":"$asset.attributes.Duration" } 
                    }
        },
        { "$project": { "_id":0,"Artist":1,"Duration": 1 }}
    ]
)
```

**Edit**

As per new edited question you can do following aggregation to get the result

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "artist": "$asset.attributes.Artist",
        "duration": "$asset.attributes.Duration"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$data"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "a": "$data.artist",
      "b": "$data.duration"
    },
    "count": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "ArtistValues": {
      "$push": "$_id.a"
    },
    "ArtistFreq": {
      "$push": "$count"
    },
    "DurationValue": {
      "$push": "$_id.b"
    },
    "durationfreq": {
      "$push": "$count"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "Artist": {
      "values": "$ArtistValues",
      "freq": "$ArtistFreq"
    },
    "Duration": {
      "values": "$DurationValue",
      "freq": "$durationfreq"
    },
    "_id": 0
  }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have one more query, while aggregating values can we get the frequency of values. so depend on frequency we can sort them and eliminate the repetitive values. ?

Comment: @Sagar you edit your question and add what you want to find out with expected output .

Comment: There is one slight problem...Values are repeated.

Comment: ohoo so in `group` replace `$push` to `$addToSet` and check .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79758/discussion-between-sagar-and-yogesh).

Comment: Multiple values in Artist doesn't reflect anything I think. any way we are considering whole Artist value as a single value.